# Flutter widget display in custom position

Tags: flutter

I am making a mobile app in Flutter. I need to display widget in random positions of my choice on the screen e.g. we can define the position of where we want to print or display something when we code in HTML.

[I took this image from this link: https://www.invisionapp.com/inside-design/design-resources/free-mobile-ui-kit-atlas/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwzxT.png)

How can I achieve display a widget in a custom position as shown in the image above?

Comment: this is something that can be achieved with `GridView` or with a package called `flutter_staggered_grid_view` , u can read the docs and see the implementation and exmaples right here : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Comment: Thanks! This worked exactly the way I wanted it to :)